# Not understanding a line of the proof of lemma 2.15 in Mendelson.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This question is from "[Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekrajicek/mendelson.pdf)" by Elliot Mendelson ; page 88 about the proof of lemma 2.15. There is one line which I don't seem to understand.What does the line below mean ?

> Call this new theory $K_0$. Its axioms are those of $K$ plus those logical axioms that involve the symbols of $K$ and the new constants.

Comment: You have a theory K with its own language, including specific constant symbols, like e.g. $\emptyset$ for set theory. You add new constants $b_0, \ldots$ and the corresponding instances of logical axioms, like e.g. $\forall x \alpha \to \alpha[b_0/x]$.

Comment: Wait , so the logical axioms are the same for all theories ?

Comment: What part of the quote do you not understand, exactly?

Comment: The text you quote is a little unclear. The second sentence is defining the axioms of $K_0$ (not describing something that has already been defined).

Comment: Logical axioms are *schemata* i.e. recipes to manufacture specific axioms for every FO language